# Is this a good approach to DRY?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My controller action is like :

```
# check if user is already working
if current_user.working?
  flash[:error] = I18n.translate 'error.working'    
  redirect_to labor_url and return          
end

# check if user is doing a quest
if current_user.has_tavern_quest?
  flash[:error] = I18n.translate 'error.has_quest'      
  redirect_to labor_url and return          
end
```

Now, this is some code that seems to be repeating itself in other controllers and their actions as well. Therefore, i thought that it would be a good idea to DRY things a little. I thought of creating a user method like :

```
def is?(states)
    possible_states = :working, :doing_tavern_quest
    # check states
    # set flash messages, do the same things as above without the redirects
end
```

The idea is that i would now just use something like that in my actions :

```
redirect_to labor_url if current_user.is?(:working, :doing_tavern_quest)
```

Do you think that is a good idea ? Is it a good way to DRY things up or i could do it in a better manner ?

Comment: DRY'ing things up is always a good idea, but you should avoid dealing with flash directly in your model.

Comment: I would agree with Pablo. This is possibly better as a method in the controller, not on the User model, since it is business logic. User should maintain state, UsersController should determine what to do with that state.

Comment: yes, i was thinking of that as well, i was also hesitant about the flashes, but i can't see a way of encapsulating it without adding the flashes in the model :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the *and return* pattern.

But unless there are lots of different dynamic conditions, why not encapsulate the User state within the model as much as possible?

Unless the controller needs to know details, how about:

```
redirect_to labor_url if current_user.busy? # no parameters
```

BTW, controller methods don't return anything, you could possibly do:

```
return redirect_to labor_url if current_user.busy?
```

Comment: "Why not encapsulate the User state within the model as much as possible?" Agreed. I like that.

Comment: That is a very nice idea there. I like that type of encapsulation.

Comment: everything seems great except from the flash messages. I don't really want to handle them inside my model. Do you think there is a better way, without writing too much in the controller ?

Comment: Well, you could always centralize common controller code in a superclass. Be careful of the *call super* design anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong in principle with current_user.is?(state) except maybe the name (is_one_of? ...)

```
def is?(states)
    possible_states = [:working, :doing_tavern_quest] # note square brackets here
    # check states
    # set flash messages, do the same things as above without the redirects
end
```

You could extract method the redirect line and create a method in the ApplicationController class so that the code is even drier (if the redirection is to the same place.)

Comment: hmm, maybe i can create a generic method that is used to set the flash and redirect, in order to avoid having to set flash in my model. Nice one :)